# Access a local variable from another function in Javascript with closure?

Tags: javascript

I am new here. I have a problem that is troubling me. I am wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction. I have the following code.

```
var f1 = function() {

  var myValue = 3;

  setTimeout((function(myValue){
    return function() { 
      f2(); 
    };
  })(myValue), 1000);

};

var f2 = function() {
  console.log(myValue);
}

f1();
```

I get myValue is not defined. What am I missing here? How can I access to myValue in f2 without making it global or passing as a parameter? Thanks in advance.

**---- Additional Info ----**

The reason why I am asking about this because I had an interview question on this. Given the following functions:

```
var func1 = function() {
  var myValue = 3;
  setTimeout(func2, 1000);
};

var func2 = function() {
  console.log(myValue);
};

func1();
```

Without moving the functions or adding parameters to the functions, only change what's inside func1. How to get myValue print in console.log.

Comment: pass it as a parameter calling `f2` from `f1`

Comment: if you can use localStorage, set the value in localStorage in f1 and read it from localStorage in f2

Comment: Read about variable scope in JS.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get it to print in the console, which is your requirement, is to simply remove the "var" in func1. So that pushes myValue up into the global scope. You wouldn't really consider this a good solution in the real world but it solves the problem. If you get the job you owe me a beer. And you should pick my answer. :)

```
var func1 = function() {
  myValue = 3;
  setTimeout(func2, 1000);
};

var func2 = function() {
  console.log(myValue);
};

func1();
```

---

**Previous answer below:**

Your function f2 is not in the same scope as myValue. You can define it within f1 like this and it will work:

```
var f1 = function() {

  var myValue = 3;

  var f2 = function() {
    console.log(myValue);
  }

  setTimeout((function(myValue){
    return function() { 
      f2(); 
    };
  })(myValue), 1000);
};

f1();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, I can't move the function. Please check my additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it, based on your clarification:

```js
var func1 = function() {
  var myValue = 3;
  window.myValue = myValue; /* Push it into the global scope, assuming you're running in a browser */
                            /* If you're running elsewhere (e.g. node.js) there are similar options */
  setTimeout( func2, 1000 );
};

var func2 = function() {
  console.log(myValue);
};

func1();
```

**Explanation:** Alternately, if you were using *this* (i.e. this.myValue), then you could use mechanisms like *call* or *apply* to just push another scope into func2, but in the exact example given in your question, pushing the variable *myValue* into global scope is the simplest solution I can think of.

**Note:** Pushing variables into global scope is different depending on whether you're running in a browser or not (e.g. node.js)

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I can't move the functions.

Comment: @WilliamNg updated answer with working solution per your clarification